# How to create a signature using RSA private key and a message. The signature will be of 256 bits in length

Tags: c#, .net

I need to use 256 bit signature to pass in a header to call Jenga api.

Below is the code which i have tried and it's working but it is giving a signature length of 71 bits not 256 bits.

```
 public static string GetSignature(byte[] privateKey, string message)
        {

            string str = null;
            try
            {
                var curve = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256k1");
                var domain = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H);

                var keyParameters = new
                        ECPrivateKeyParameters(new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(privateKey),
                        domain);                
                ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withECDSA");

                signer.Init(true, keyParameters);
                signer.BlockUpdate(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message), 0, message.Length);
                var signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
                str = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return str;
        }
```

I expect the signature length of 256 bits long but the actual output is 71 bits long and that is wrong.

Comment: Does it have to be EC? where did you get the requirements for the signature from? do you have the code in another language?

Comment: Because at least according to quick googling, you can make do with a simple SHA256, not ec: https://github.com/Kihagi/jenga-api-generate-signature-java

Comment: I am using Jenga api and the requirement for signature in it is 256 bits length.

Comment: Where is the EC requirements? 256 bits doesnt mean EC nor DSA nor specific algorithm, even

Comment: Can you get your private key in the form of `X509Certificate2` object?

Comment: I am getting RSA private key in the .key format